# "I determined to beat him, even if it means getting to his story first."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I determined to beat him, even if it means *getting to* his story first.

In this context, what's  the meaning of **getting to**?

Comment: *I **am** determined beat him...* It's not obvious *exactly* what your cited writer means, but the basic words are equivalent to him saying *...even if I have to "get to" his story before he does* (literally, ***arrive there before him***). Maybe "he" is a reporter who is *assigned* stories to cover (which requires being at some relevant place where things are known to be happening). So perhaps it's like the reporter in [*Nightcrawler](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2872718/) (2014)*, getting to the "hot news" locations before others.

Comment: 'I determined **to** beat him' (made up my mind) or 'I am,/was determined **to** beat him.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Getting to" means the same as "arrive at".

> We will get to London in 3 hours.

Story here means a piece of journalism: A news report or an investigative article.

If you "get to" a story it means that you, as a reporter arrive at the scene of the story.

> There's a big fire starting downtown! We've gotta get to this story, take some pictures and interview everybody.

A reporter might be assigned a story by a newspaper editor. That is then "his story".  The narrator says "even if it means getting to his story first" which means "even if I report on his story before he does". This is stealing his assignment.

The style is colloquial